# bash error in sort "sort: write failed: standard output: Broken pipe"

Tags: bash, sorting, broken-pipe

When I run this script I recieve an error message with: "sort: write failed: standard output: Broken pipe"

If someone can help me it would be awesome, I am going crazy with this error

the input file is a list of files that all contain DNA sequences in a FASTA format, so each file has several sequences (each sequence in a single line) with the format: 
in $1 (Identifier) in $2,3,4,5,6,7&8 (more values) in $9 (the DNA sequence)

Then I want select each of this sequences by number of sequences ($common_hits) in each file (this number is not a fix value but i set 6 for the example)
-All the files with less than 6 sequences must be removed
-Files with 6 sequences are ok
-The files with more than 6 sequences have to be reduced to 6 sequences (these sequences are selected by the higher values of field $5)

the output files must have all 6 sequences and the sequence (field $9) has to be in the line after the identifier

I am not removing the originals files with more than 6 sequences for now, because I want to be sure it works

```
par_list=`ls -1 *BR`

common_hits="6"

for i in ${par_list}

do

   if [ "`cat ${i} | wc -l`" -lt "${common_hits}" ]
   then
      rm -f ${i}
   elif [ "`cat ${i} | wc -l`" -gt "${common_hits}" ]
   then
      cat ${i} | sort -nr -k 5 | head -n ${common_hits} | \
      awk '{print $1"    " $2"    " $3"    " $4"    " $5"    " $6"    " $7"           "$8 ; print $9}' > ${i}.ph 
   fi

done
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow site, please wrap up your code(s) into code tags as per forum rules and explain the issues more clearly so that we could try to help you, thank you.

Comment: I could see we could make lot of changes into your script, could you please post 2 things, 1st what is your requirement(with sample Input_file and expected output_file), 2nd in case you want the same script only, use set -x in the starting of your script and show us the output, though you have to still let us know about your requirement(what is Input_file and about output_file in code tags) please.

Comment: thank you for the advise, I hope it is easier to understand now

Comment: Thank you for adding information, could you please also add sample input and expected sample output too in code tags.

Comment: what do you mean by code tags?, a file of the input and a file of the output?

Comment: Every one of those `cat` program calls is unnecessary, `wc` and `sort` both take an input filename as their rightmost parameter.

Comment: No point to `head | awk` either -- `awk` can do the work of picking out which lines to read itself. `awk '{ print ... } NR > 5 { exit }'

Comment: As another aside -- see [Why you shouldn't parse the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). The loop is better written (prone to fewer unexpected misbehaviors) as `for i in *BR`.

Comment: Thanks for the advises, I will try to improve my code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`sort | head` **always** reports an error, if `head` exits (or otherwise closes its stdin) before `sort` has written all its output (as will be the case, if the stream written by `sort` is much longer than that consumed by `head`). This is by-design: If `sort` can't write all its output, it's expected to fail; if it ignored such failures, it would also ignore cases where it couldn't write its output for other reasons (disk full, broken network connection, etc.

There's nothing unusual or undesirable about this. If you don't care about the error, ignore it, and check the number of lines of output from the pipeline to determine whether you had an error condition instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, so even if there is an error with sort it shouldnt affect to my output?

Comment: Right -- the "error" is just that `sort` isn't able to write more than `$common_hits` lines.

Comment: In other words, "Broken pipe" errors are often harmless and can be ignored or, if you're lucky, even suppressed.

Comment: BTW, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds; you've got a bunch of quoting bugs. They may not be causing immediate effects now, but that doesn't mean they won't ever.

Comment: but then sort is not sorting checking all the sequences? I nedd to sort the sequences comparing all the sequences

Comment: In order to get that `common_hits` lines of output, it absolutely *does* need to read the complete input stream. What part of my answer or comment do you read as claiming it doesn't do so?

Comment: Pedantically, this error is caused by `write` syscall raising `SIGPIPE`. It is possible for (last) `write` to return successfully, yet for `head` never read it and not observe this error.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, as someone known to get a bit pedantic myself, I'm happy to rephrase to be more precise. Better?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Definitely better.

Comment: You were right! The output files are correct, I panicked when I saw the error. Thanks to everyone

Comment: Hello again, I am running the script normally but sometimes the .error file has also this message: "sort: fflush failed: standard output: Broken pipe
sort: write error". Is this normal too? it does not affect the output?

Comment: Yes, it's normal. No, it doesn't change the output -- just means that the failure happened while flushing buffers rather than doing a write into a buffer (and letting the C library decide when to flush) -- but it's the exact same error with the exact same effects, just happening with different timing.

Comment: Thank you so much!